# XSL: Sort a node list passed as a param to a template

Tags: sorting, xslt, parameter-passing

I'm facing a weird problem (IMHO) which, in short, is:

a node list passed as a parameter to a template can't be sorted.

Here's an example.

The input file is:

```xml
<root>
    <a>BBB</a>
    <a>AAA</a>
</root>
```

And the transformation is:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
      <xsl:call-template name="processThis">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodeList" select="/*/a"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="processThis">
    <xsl:param name="nodeList" />

      <xsl:for-each select="$nodeList">
        <xsl:sort /><!-- ***** This causes the problem -->
        <xsl:variable name="thisVal" select="." />
        <result value="{$thisVal}" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output is:

```xml
<Root>
    <result value="AAA" />
    <result value="BBB" />
</Root>
```

But if I run the transformation, just an empty 'Root' element is generated, without child nodes.

If I comment out the line marked with '*****', the generated Root element does contain child elements, but unsorted (as one would expect in this case).

If I process the elements directly (and not in a template passing the list to process as a parameter), then I can use 'sort', and everything works as expected. Here is the 'direct' transformation:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/a">
                <xsl:sort />
                <xsl:variable name="thisVal" select="." />
                <result value="{$thisVal}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So my question is: why isn't a list passed as a parameter to a template processed with a 'sort' option?

**Update from Mar 07 2016:**

XmlSpy and some online XSL processors deliver the expected (sorted) output.

I've tried it with a standalone Java program, and it gives me the wrong result. Here's the program:

```java
package my.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Transform {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFileName = "Q:\\MiscThings\\t\\a.xml";
        String xslFileName = "Q:\\MiscThings\\t\\trans.xsl";

        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(inputFileName));
        Source xslSource = new StreamSource(new File(xslFileName));

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Result transformationResult = new StreamResult(stringWriter);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, transformationResult);

        stringWriter.flush();
        String xmlResult = stringWriter.toString();

        System.out.println(xmlResult);
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Which processor are you using?

Comment: I use the one built in in Ant (I start the transformation from within an Ant script), I don't know exactly what it is.

Do you get identical results in both cases?

Comment: @fml2 - Here's an example of it working correctly. http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7n5 Try any of the processors available; they all sort correctly. (I added `indent="yes"` for readability.)

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: @Daniel Haley: As I found out, these were different versions. At work it was Java 7, at home I tried it with Java 6 and Java 8 -- all with the same result. At home, I tried it from within Eclipse, at work I run it from the command line (but still via Ant).

Comment: I've now tried to run the transformation via other programs (XmlSpy, a manually programmed java), and indeed -- the problem does not occur. So it must be somehow related to Ant.

Comment: Hrm... I must again correct myself. I ran the java program in different environments. Some of the give the correct result, and in others the error occurs (i.e. the wrong output is generated). I will investigate it further.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by explicitly specifying the XSL processor to be used. It seems to me that the JDK I use (I tried JRE7 and JRE8) includes an older version of XSL processor which does not process files correctly.

I downloaded Xalan 2.7.2 and specified its JAR in the 'xslt' ant task -- and immediately got the correct result.

I also tried saxon 9, and also got the correct result.

I'm surprised by the fact that a modern JRE is packaged with a flawed XSL processor. The transformation I perform is not a complicated one in my view.